# Показать div при наведении

Tags: html, css

Почему у меня при наведении на Contact us всплывает снизу див, а при наведении на "Products" - нет?

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red; }
  nav > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; }
    nav > a:hover + .products_pop_up {
      display: block;
      background-color: green; }
  nav > .products_pop_up {
    display: none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New vision</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <a href="">Main</a>
    <a href="" id="products_nav">Products</a>
    <a href="">Resources</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Contact us</a>

    <div class="products_pop_up">Текст</div>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Соседний селектор ищется так `nav>#products_nav:hover~.products_pop_up`

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

nav>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>#products_nav:hover~.products_pop_up,
nav>a:hover+.products_pop_up {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}

nav>.products_pop_up {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Main</a>
  <a href="" id="products_nav">Products</a>
  <a href="">Resources</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Contact us</a>

  <div class="products_pop_up">Текст</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Я хотел что-то подобное добавить, чуть проще только, но только я не понял смысл в этом, если все равно все ломается потом.

Comment: @Axenow тоже самое сработает если поставить `nav>a:hover~.products_pop_up`

Comment: Да можно еще проще, просто поднять div под Products, тоже будет работать, но все равно все сломается. )

Comment: @Axenow  как понять сломается ?

Comment: Прошу прощения - я немного ошибся. Код неверно вставился. Вы правы - все красиво и ровно.

Comment: @Axenow второй вариант [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/WaxOzO)

Comment: Никита - все работает - это я промахнулся.

Comment: @Axenow тогда галочку нажми

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием, но не вопрос задавал. )

Comment: @Axenow точно точно ....